# mongoosejs find specific record

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i want to find a specific record in mongoose. i'm trying to make a login/register form and im kind of new to node.js..

for now i have this code:

```
app.post('/register', function(request, response)
{
    console.log('REGISTER OK');

    //set connection to mongodb.
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    //Connect to mongodb.
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback()
    {
        console.log('connection succeed.');

        //Create User schema.
        var userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
        {
            username: String,
            password: String
        });

        //User model.
        var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

        var user = new UserModel(
        {
            username: request.body.username,
            password: request.body.password
        });

        user.save(function(error, data)
        {
            if(error)
                console.log(error);

            else
            {
                response.render('register',
                {
                    'Title': Title,
                    'result': data
                });

                UserModel.find(function(error, data)
                {
                    if(error)
                        console.log(error);

                    else
                        console.log(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i dont quite get the find method of mongoose, i just need to find the username in order to do some function, is there a function that moongose has to avoid record if this exists already?

Answer (score 1):

```
UserModel.findOne ({ name: "someName" }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) console.log (err);
  if (!user) console.log ('user not found');
  // do something with user
});
```